# Wordpress - How to insert code after SUBMIT button in comments form

Tags: wordpress, themes, recaptcha

I nedd to inser this code after Submit button in comments form (need to insert in child theme)
My Site: https://www.mundoemalerta.com/seguro-de-vida-iad-e-itp-no-credito-habitacao-descubra-as-diferencas

Code to insert below

This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
    [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) and
    [Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms) apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function add_text_below_comment_form(){
    echo 'This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google Privacy Policy and Terms of Service apply.';
});

add_action('comment_form', 'add_text_below_comment_form');
```

Comment: Your theme is using the native comment form so this should work. Where did you place this code?

Comment: Style.css in child theme

Comment: @Viriato74 - That code is PHP. You can't put it in a CSS file. Try placing it in your `functions.php` file.

Comment: Create a functions.php file in your child theme. strart that file of with <?php and on the next line place my code snippet.

Comment: Put the ?> below my code snippet! <?php starts a php block, and ?> ends the block. You inserted my php code outside of the php block.